# How do I stop Chrome from adjusting volume?

Tags: google-chrome, audio

On my Windows 10 machine, Chrome seems to be turning down my volume, often muting it.

It seems to do this if Chrome is in focus or not. I have re-installed Chrome and the situation continues.

Any ideas on how to fix this? (Other than switching browsers)

This is what appears on my monitor when the issue is happening:
[image: Chrome muting sound]

Comment: Why do you think chrome is adjusting the volume? The screen above is shown if you are playing audio/video in chrome (in focus or not in focus) and click on physical volume up or down button (in keyboard or any other device). It might be issue in the your keyboard? or the volume buttons.

Comment: Thanks - I tried swapping speakers. Now I'll try swapping keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:-

- Open Start menu and search for Change Sound Settings.
- When the Sound Dailog Box appears go to the **Communications** tab.
- Select the **Do Nothing** Option and **Click OK**.

Comment: Thanks @Squigga. I tried this but it turns out it wasn't my issue. (a nice settings change anyway!)

Answer (score 1):

@jhamu was on the right track.

The issue was with my keyboard.

It appeared to be a Chrome issue because I have YouTube open almost all the time. When Chrome is playing sound, the volume image shows the words "Chrome.exe" when adjusting the volume with the keyboard control.